# What is the meaning of Star symbol * in Hex data?

Tags: hexdump, hex

I see sometimes star symbol (*) in the hex editor, like

```
...
00001d0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
00001f0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0008 0000 0000 0000
...
```

It is probably some sort of separator. 
However, there are many other separators too. 
What is the meaning of this star symbol in hex data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means that one or more lines were suppressed, because they are identical to the previous line; in this case, it means that the line starting at `00001e0` is all zeroes, same as that starting at `00001d0`.

To determine the number of deleted lines, you need to look at the addresses involved and the length of each line; in this case, a single line was deleted.

If you're using `od`, this is controlled by the `-v` flag. By default `od` will suppress duplicate lines, `-v` tells it not to.

Comment: I think `-v` flag is not suppressing duplicate lines, so I do not see anymore duplicate lines and no star symbols. I am viewing binary data and splitting it to chunks and then converting back to smaller binary files. Do you think I should use `-v` flag in this kind of task? I think yes because I should not alter (suppress) the original data but just split by a deliminator.

Comment: If you're manipulating binary data by converting to and from hex dumps you could take a look at `xxd` instead. But yes, I'd recommend `od -v` if you're rebuilding the original data...

Comment: Command `od -v` gives me six letter strings like `000000 042577` which I think is an octave format. Another command `hexdump -v` gives me also four letter stringse like `457f 464c` but with some octave options `hexdump -vo` gives three letter words like `000000 177 105 ...`. I need to open a new thread for this issue here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/212334/16920